# Reconstructing a vector after projection

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, high-dimensional

Suppose one has a matrix of data $X$, which is $n$ observations by $p$ dimensions.

Let $P_\perp$ be a projection onto some $k<p$ dimensional subspace. Suppose one computes the principal direction of $P_\perp(X)$. Is there a principled way to reconstruct this principal direction in the full $p$-space?

Comment: When you say that $P$ is a projection onto a $k$-dimensional subspace, do you mean that $P:\mathbb R^p \to \mathbb R^k$ or that $P:\mathbb R^p \to \mathbb R^p$? In other words, is $P$ a $p\times k$ or $p\times p$ matrix? In the latter case, you don't need to do anything, your vector $\mathbf v$ in the subspace is already $p$-dimensional. In the former case, you need to project it back via $P^+ \mathbf v$, where $P^+$ is a pseudo-inverse. If $P$ has orthonormal columns (like e.g. if it is composed of some PCA axes), then $P^+$ is simply $P^\top$.

Answer (score 1):

So I think reconstructing a matrix after PCA is the problemyou are asking. If you want to get in the weeds, here's a nice [paper](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~dfg/ProbabilisticInference/IDAPILecture15.pdf) that made sense to me. It walks through the steps of reconstruction on page 4.

Here's my explanation:

After finding the principle components for a matrix (M x N), we have two matrices.

1 - Matrix of eigenvectors which are our principle components (K x N).

2 - Matrix of projected data relative to the principle components (M x k).

Now, we want to reverse the process with our reduced data to create a matrix of the original dimensions. To do this, we simply take the inner product of Matrix 2 and Matrix 1 and voila, were back to where we started, just with bare necessities this time.

Hopefully this get's you a little bit further to understanding this (if you haven't already figured it out). Let me know if you still have any questions.